# Money transfer and subscribe workflow in stripe using node js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, stripe-payments

I'm totally new to Stripe, we are using that as our payment gateway. I want to know how to transfer money from my customer credit to my stripe account and how to use subscription using nodeJs.

Answer (score 0):

My function on node.js app to make payments

```
function pay( number, exp_month, exp_year, cvc){            
            let stripeAmount: 1
            const card = {
                number,
                exp_month,
                exp_year,
                cvc
            }

            let chargeIdToRefund

            const payment = await stripe.tokens
                .create({
                    card
                })
                .then((token) =>
                    stripe.customers.create({
                        email,
                        source: token.id
                    })
                )
                .then((customer) =>
                    stripe.charges.create({
                        amount: stripeAmount,
                        currency: 'usd',
                        customer: customer.id
                    })
                )
                .then((charge) => {
                    chargeIdToRefund = charge.id
                    return Payment.create({
                        user_id,
                        amount: stripeAmount
                    })
                })
                .then(async (payment) => {
                    if (payment) { ... } else throw { charge: chargeIdToRefund }
                }).catch(async (err) => {
                    if (err.charge)
                        return await stripe.refunds
                            .create({
                                charge: err.charge
                            })
                            .then((refund) => {
                                if (refund.status === 'succeeded'){ ... }
                            })
                    else return err.message
                })
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, have you done subscription with stripe payment?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by following out guide to accept a payment via [Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?integration=checkout) or using [Elements](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?integration=elements) on your own site.

If you have more specific questions while working through that, please update your question and leave a comment for clarification.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, have you done subscription with stripe payment? can you help me with that

Comment: I have and I can, but is this related to your question above? If so, I'd suggest editing with additional details of your specific questions for the subscription flow. If it's separate, I'd suggest creating a new question. Are you planning on using Checkout or Elements for your integration?

Comment: Thanks for the reply and I have edited the question. we are planning to use subscription using elements because we need to do payments in backend for Data collection